# how I can report the result of binary logistic regression?

Tags: regression, logistic, chi-squared-test, odds-ratio, reporting

We are conducting research to examine a relationship between some triggers and migraine with aura.

therefore, we conduct logistic regression for the significant relationships to know the adjusted odd ratio. (odd ratio of diagnosed/undiagnosed)
however, the odd ratio is less than 1

[image]

so should I report the result as (it is less likely to the patient who is diagnosed to have migraine with aura when he eats hotdog)? or am I misunderstanding the interpretation?

second question: how I can report this result
[image]

thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could report it that way.

The probability of the outcome when `eat_hotdog17=0` is

$$ p = \dfrac{1}{1+\exp(-0.814)}  \approx 30\% $$

When `eat_hotdog=1`

$$ p = \dfrac{1}{1+\exp(-0.814 - 0.464)}  \approx 21\% $$